# Activiti Integration with Mule

Tags: mule, activiti

When I try to run the activiti - mule integration example in Embedded mode, I am getting the below error -

org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Could not find required org.mule.api.connector.ConnectorOperationLocator in the registry under key _muleConnectorMessageProcessorLocator
    at org.mule.client.DefaultLocalMuleClient.getConnectorMessageProcessLocator(DefaultLocalMuleClient.java:61)

I could not find anything on this error. Does anyone have any idea? Also, is Enterprise edition of Mule required for remote mule activiti integration? I am using the community edition.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information around the context including your configuration, mule version and version of the activiti module.

Comment: I am using activiti 5.17 and mule-module-activiti version 3.1.1
I am trying to run a simple flow to log incoming message to a queue and return a message in response.